# Google Identity Platform - Verification Code Text language

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sms, google-identity-toolkit

I'm using [sendVerificationCode](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v1/accounts/sendVerificationCode) API (with the recaptchaToken paramter) to send OTP SMS to my device. However, I'm always receiving text messages in English.

How do I specify the language code for an SMS message when calling the sendVerificationCode API ?

Comment: can you also share the request with headers you are sending with masking the API key.